# Where can I find broad White Papers on Usability Experiments

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, research, usability-study

For example studies on what makes for the most effective shopping cart, how people prefer to view photos in their browsers and on their phone, what people appreciate in a search engine, whether left hand or top navigation performs better, etc.

Resources that I can use to inform my decisions when I set out to build something.

Are there any sites that aggregate this kind of research / experimentation?

Answer (score 1):

The Nielsen Norman Group conducts excellent user experience research.  They post articles for some research and make reports available for a fee for others.

Here are two articles touching on the examples you gave:

- [Photos as Web Content](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/photos-as-web-content/)
- [Mega Menus Work Well for Site Navigation](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/)

Comment: This was going to be my response as well. NNG does some really great research, I'd definitely follow them to get their updates.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good resources at [SURL.org](http://surl.org) and I strongly suggest becoming a member of [ACM.org](http://acm.org) as they have a very deep library of research. Not a lot is directly targeted at the things you may want, but there is a lot of research that you can apply to things you are doing.